# Is there a Modern C++ way for a constructor to know its 'container' class?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have two classes, `Parent` and `Child`. Any instances of the `Child` class **must** occur as members of a `Parent` class, and the `Child` class has, as a data member, a pointer to that `Parent`. Thus, the `Child` class has a *single* constructor that takes said pointer as its sole argument (and there is, by design, no default constructor).

At its simplest, then, we have code like the following (I have included the `DoSomething` functions so that compilers won't optimize-away the `pParent` member, which is otherwise unused in this MCVE):

```cpp
class Parent; // Declaration to enable use of pointer in Child

void DoSomething(Parent* p, int x);

class Child {
private:
    Parent* pParent;
public:
    Child(Parent* pp) : pParent{pp} {}
    // Would like a 'default'-style constructor, like below, where "nullptr" is replaced with a pointer-to-container
//    Child(Parent* pp = nullptr) : pParent{ pp } {}
public:
    void DoSomething(int x) { ::DoSomething(pParent, x); }
};

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
public:
    Child Child1{ this };
//  Child Child2; // error: 'Child': no appropriate default constructor available
};
```

As I have used in the above code, I can declare/instantiate `Child` members using the `{ this }` initializer syntax; however, I typically have several thousand such instances in my projects (and there a number of different Child classes), and I was wondering if "Modern C++" (I generally use the `C++17` standard) provides any way for the constructor to be declared in a manner *similar in form* to the commented-out version, but replacing the default argument value (`nullptr`) with some kind of 'token' (or keyword) that will be converted to a pointer to the 'containing' `Parent` class at compile-time, and thus hugely reducing the coding burden? Something like this:

```cpp
Child(Parent* pp = id_of_containing_class) : pParent{ pp } {}
```

I am still in the process of getting fully 'up-to-speed' with the new language features since `C++11`, and have not yet found such a tool. But there are *many* excellent coders here on SO who are far more familiar with what can and cannot be done!

*(To provide some context for this: the `Child` classes represent customized controls in customized dialog-boxes, derived from the `Parent` class.)*

Comment: Do you often create `Child` instances dynamically?

Comment: @Botje Child instances are ***only*** ever created when the parent (dialog) is created. This is generally done by either automatic creation (function-local declared, like: `Parent MyBox(args)`) or as a `std::unique_ptr`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Is this a Huge burden: `struct Parent{Parent():child1{this}{}child child1;};` ?

Comment: @Ayxan It does become rather tedious when I have (say) 30 or 40 child objects in a given derivative of `Parent`.

Comment: Any chance of using a singleton to keep a mapping between parents and children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a small runtime cost you can store a pointer to the currently-under-construction `Parent`. The base `ParentMarker` instance will be created before any children of `Parent`:

```
class Parent;

class ParentMarker {
  public:
    thread_local static inline Parent* dynamic_parent = nullptr;
    ParentMarker();
};

class Parent : public ParentMarker {
...
};

ParentMarker::ParentMarker() {
  dynamic_parent = static_cast<Parent *>(this);
}

class Child {
  public:
    Child(Parent * pp = nullptr) 
     : pParent(pp ? pp : ParentMarker::dynamic_parent) {}
    Parent *pParent;
};
```

Of course this falls apart if you start nesting Parents and creating Children dynamically.

Comment: Looks interesting! The run-time cost is unimportant (creating a dialog-box, or similar). I'll give this a 'test-drive' on some real-world code, and get back in a little while. 

Comment: @Ayxan Forgot the `inline` keyword and the `pParent` member in my hurry. Try now?

Comment: @Botje now it compiles fine

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a Modern C++ way for a constructor to know its 'container' class?

No. It is not possible, in the constructor, to distinguish whether the object is being constructed as a sub-object, or what is the type of the super-object.

Passing `this` to the child is a good solution for your case.

There is no standard solution, but if you really want default construction to work, that may be possible, if you can use some non-portable tricks. It can only work if the default construction is only ever used when `Child` is that particular member of `Parent`. This can be reasonably achieved by making the constructor private, and declaring `Parent` as friend of `Child`. Or `Child` could be a nested class of `Parent`.

Once we have the guarantee that we are constructing a particular member, there are platform specific macros that give us a pointer to the super object (I got list from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240273/a-portable-way-to-calculate-pointer-to-the-whole-structure-using-pointer-to-a-fi), but looked up originals)

[Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/include/linux/kernel.h):

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
const typeof(((type *)0)->member) * __mptr = (ptr); \
    (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member)); })
```

That one uses GCC extensions `typeof` and statement expressions. `typeof` may be replaced with `decltype` in C++. `offsetof` is guaranteed to only work for standard layout types (otherwise conditionally supported since C++17 (probably not supported if there's virtual inheritance), unconditionally UB before that).

[Windows (MinGW version)](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-tools/widl/include/winnt.h)

```
#define CONTAINING_RECORD(address, type, field) \
  ((type *)((PCHAR)(address) - offsetof(type, field)))
```

[FeeBSD (windows compatibility)](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/compat/ndis/ntoskrnl_var.h)

```
#define CONTAINING_RECORD(addr, type, field)    \
    ((type *)((vm_offset_t)(addr) - (vm_offset_t)(&((type *)0)->field)))
```

That implementation relies on `Child` type not having an overloaded addressof operator.

Given any of those, you could use `pParent{CONTAINING_RECORD(this, Parent, Child2)}`. If the `Child` is only ever that member, then there would not even be a need to store the pointer in `Child`; `CONTAINING_RECORD` is a compile time constant operation.