# C++ static const integral variable usage via pointer/reference?

Tags: c++, static, constants, standards

When declaring and using static const integrals, I find it convenient and natural to use the object reference I'm working with to access the variable, rather than fully-qualifying it with the class name.  I'm wondering if there is a downside to this?  Take for example:

```
class MyLongClassNameIdRatherNotHaveEverywhere {
public:
    static const int Len = 6;
    //...
    void otherInterestingThings();
    void someWorkToDo();
};

int main() {
    MyLongClassNameIdRatherNotHaveEverywhere *lcn = new MyLongClassNameIdRatherNotHaveEverywhere;
    lcn->someWorkToDo();
    cout << "the length is: " << lcn->Len << endl;
    delete lcn;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the `lcn->Len`... it's really a constant, and in fact if `lcn` were null, `lcn->Len` would still compile and run just fine.  I could have written `MyLongClassNameIdRatherNotHaveEverywhere::Len` there instead, which certainly makes it more obvious (to me at least) that this is a constant.  Are there other drawbacks?

Comment: *"in fact if lcn were null, this still compiles and runs just fine"* That doesn't make it legal. It's undefined behavior to do that.

Comment: @jrok: No, it is not. You are not accessing the object, just using the object type to access a static member of the class. The pointer is *not* dereferenced and there is no undefined behavior involved.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Do we mean the same thing? I meant `X* lcn = nullptr; lcn->foo;` kind of thing.

Comment: Note that `((MyLongClassNameIdRatherNotHaveEverywhere*)0)->Len` is not undefined behavior, it is 6.

Comment: @jrok: You can use `obj.x` and `objptr->x` to access a `static` member `x`. The syntax allows it, and regardless of what it looks like it does *not* access the object. It is just an uncommon way of typing `decltype(obj)::x` (that predates `decltype`)

Comment: @jrok: After reviewing the wording in the standard I think you are right. While the member is not part of the object, the standard requires that the expression *is* evaluated, in this case that (I understand) means dereferencing the pointer (even if the object is never accessed) and that is either undefined behavior or close enough not to want to do it :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas From what I read in 5.2.5 in n3337, expression `E1->E2` is converted to `(*(E1)).E2` and both sub expressions are evaluated even if the result is not neccesary to determine the result of entire expression (see sub-text 64 on the same page). Surely that means `nullptr` gets dereferenced? EDIT: ninja'd :)

Comment: I'll point out that it's not being dereferenced in either MSVC or GNU compilers... perhaps it's just being "optimized out"?

Comment: @mark Probably. It's one of those UB's that'll just work in practice.

Comment: Here's another thing to consider: look up how the `offsetof` macro is defined.  Here's Microsoft's in stddef, exactly what I'm talking about: `(size_t)&reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>((((s *)0)->m))`... doesn't seem to me undefined behavior would be part of the standard definitions...?

Comment: @mark That's a [known issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433339/does-the-offsetof-macro-from-stddef-h-invoke-undefined-behaviour). Compiler writers have the freedom to use all the UB and black magic they want (and define it for their particular platform) as long as they implement the correct observable behavior. The user code doesn't have that freedom.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from weirdness, I can see a drawback in case operator -> is overloaded...
Scope resolution operator :: btw, cannot be overloaded.