# Accessing a member variable through the parent class and an offset

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, private, virtual-inheritance, offsetof

I put the tag `language lawyer`, although I have the feeling that this is on the wrong side of the standard boundary. I haven't seen a conversation exactly on this point, and but I had at work, so I would like to have some certainty about this.

The issue is accessing (potentially) private fields of virtual base classes. Say I compute the offset of a private field of a class, and then use this offset outside the class to access (read/write) the member variable at this location.

I saw that there is an extension for GCC and clang `offsetof` (this one is conditionally defined in C++17, what does it mean?), and using it is equivalent to some pointer arithmetic like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int a{};
public:
    int aa{};
    static ptrdiff_t getAOffset()
    {
        A instance;
        return reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(static_cast<const void*>(&instance)) - reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(static_cast<const void*>(&(instance.a)));
        //return offsetof(A, a); // "same" as this call to offset
    }

    int get() const
    {
        return a;
    }
};

class B: public virtual A
{
};

void update_field(char* pointer, ptrdiff_t offset, int value)
{
    int* field = reinterpret_cast<int*>(pointer + offset);
    *field = value;
}

void modify_a(B& instance)
{
    update_field(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dynamic_cast<A*>(&instance)), A::getAOffset(), 1);
}

int main()
{
    B instance;

    std::cout << instance.get() << std::endl;

    modify_a(instance);

    std::cout << instance.get() << std::endl;
}
```

I also made a coliru (pedantic) that doesn't complain, but still...
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faecd0b248eff651

Is there something in the standard that authorizes this or is this in undefined behavior land? Happy to see also if there is a difference between the standards.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433339/does-the-offsetof-macro-from-stddef-h-invoke-undefined-behaviour

Comment: Interesting. OK, so `offsetof` would be tagged as UB by clang UBSAN (if I don't use the macro, or is it the volatile?)... What about computing the offset on a real class?

Comment: I get where you are coming from, but to me the important part is remembering that `private` makes it hard, but it can't make it impossible, to get at a variable. Like any wall, put in the effort and you'll get through it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Some points of view are that breaking encapsulation this way is not correct C++. Then is accessing a variable through a class pointer + offset valid?

Comment: I’m probably misquoting, but Bjarne Stroustrup said that access controls protect against mistakes, not malice.

Comment: Why does the virtual base class matter here?

Comment: @geza I don't think it will, as there is only instance of `A`. The usual pattern where this occurs is multiple diamond patterns.

Comment: If you publish the offset, you might as well just publish a pointer-to-member and make it 100% kosher.

Comment: @geza — the virtual base matters because the offset within the `B` object is not fixed. Without the virtual base `offsetof` would give the correct value.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Hmm. Maybe I don't see something trivial, but this code calculates offset from `A`. There's a cast (which is unnecessarily a dynamic_cast, as a simple static_cast would do the job), which goes `B` to `A`. So the offset is calculated based on `A`, isn't it?

Comment: @TC well, the offset is actually stored in another class, where we store thousands of other such offsets, and they then used in different ways to get to the fields (of different type, of course). What do you mean by pointer to member is that context?

Comment: @geza indeed, static_cast is enough in this case, but I thought dynamic was required for multiple virtual inheritance to get to the actual base pointer (imaging that there could be several layers of virtual inheritance).

Comment: Bumping this again. `offsetof` is conditionally defined in C++17, what does it mean?

Comment: [Conditionally Supported](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.cond.supp): Not required to be supported, implementation documents if it does.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: you can use `static_cast` in the case of multiple inheritance as  well. It's not a problem using `dynamic_cast`, as the compiler will use `static_cast`  under the hood, it's just a little bit misleading. I think T.C. meant that instead of using an offset, you can just use a pointer to member (`int A::*`).

Comment: @geza Oh, OK, that could work as well. I'll investigate this in the future, thanks for the reference. For dyncamic_cast vs static_cast, are you sure this is true for multiple virtual inheritance? The position of the pointer is only known at run time, not compile time.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: yes. In this case, the compiler will generate a little code for `static_cast` as well (fetching the offset from the virtual table). `static_cast` doesn't always mean that "no code generated".

Comment: Thanks for the note :)

Comment: If you need this for production code, you seemingly have a bigger problem than mere standard compliance. Perhaps you are looking at an instance of the XY problem.

Comment: By "pointer to member" people normally mean [pointer to member](https://www.google.com/search?q=pointer+to+member). If you are not familiar with the concept, you need to stop whatever you are doing and hit those search results.