# Get pointer to struct by pointer to its member

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a **portable** way to get a pointer to a structure if you have a pointer to a member of that structure?

There is a linked list implementation in Linux kernel ([1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/include/linux/list.h)):

```
struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                  struct list_head *prev,
                  struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    prev->next = new;
}

static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
     __list_add(new, head, head->next);
}

#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

The idea is that this implementation is generic. You can use it with any `struct` type:

```
struct my_struct {
    int my_data;

    struct list_head node;
};

void example()
{
    struct list_head head;
    struct my_struct element1 = { 1 };
    struct my_struct element2 = { 2 };

    head.next = head.prev = &head;   // head <-> head
    list_add(&element1.node, &head); // head <-> {1} <-> head
    list_add(&element2.node, &head); // head <-> {2} <-> {1} <-> head

    struct my_struct *front_element = list_entry(&head.next, struct my_struct, node);

    printf("front element data: %d\n", front_element->my_data); // will print "2"
}
```

Elements of `list_head` are linked with each other, but there are only pointers to `list_head` and there are no pointers to `my_struct` (that contains `list_head` inside). However having a pointer to the `node` member of `my_struct`, you can convert this pointer to a pointer to `my_struct` itself using the `list_entry` macro. This is done using tricky pointer arithmetic (the offset of the member in the struct is subtracted from the address of the member).

But the implementation of the `container_of` macro is not portable because it uses *gcc* extensions and deferencing of null pointer (which is generally UB):

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Is there a way to make a portable implementation of this macro?

Comment: Sorry, if this is a dup. I really couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to add `void* ptr` to `list_head` and set it to pointer to `my_struct` in each node. But there is a small waste of resources in this case (each node contains an additional pointer, and each node requires additional initialization).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269685/kernels-container-of-any-way-to-make-it-iso-conforming) what you're looking for?

Comment: @RobertDerber, oh yeah. Exactly. Thank you! It seems that my google-fu is still bad -_-

Comment: BTW, the linked list implementation that uses `container_of`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50619249/5447906