# Trouble with signature of function to add node to end of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

In a program I'm writing I need a linked list, so it's a pretty specific implementation. It needs:

1. the ability to add a node to the end
2. the ability to remove a node whose data matches a specified value

The data is a cstring, no more than 20 characters in length. I'm not very experienced with C and am getting errors with the following signature `void addToEnd(llist root, char entery[51])`. I tried replacing `llist` with `node` but then the error is "unknown type name node". How can I get rid of this?

Here's the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
  char entery[51];
  struct node* next;
} llist;

/*may be losing root address permanently*/
void addToEnd(llist root, char entery[51])
{
    while(root->next != NULL)
        root = root->next;
    node last = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->next = last;
    strcpy(last, entery);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->next = NULL;
    strcpy(root->entery, "Hello");

    struct node *conductor = root;//points to a node while traversing the list

    if(conductor != 0)
        while(conductor->next != 0)
            conductor = conductor->next;

    /* Creates a node at the end of the list */
    conductor->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    conductor = conductor->next;

    if (conductor == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Out of memory" );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    /* initialize the new memory */
    conductor->next = NULL;
    strcpy(conductor->entery, " world\n");

    addToEnd(root, " at the");
    addToEnd(root, " end");

    /*print everything in list*/
    conductor = root;
    if(conductor != NULL)
    {
        while(conductor->next != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", conductor->entery);
            conductor = conductor->next;
        }
        printf("%s", conductor->entery);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

One thing I'm unclear about, is in all the examples I've seen is they [typedef the struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982388/linked-list-in-c). Why? Let me elaborate: how do you know if you want to be passing just `node` or `struct node`. Also I don't really see the point, `struct node` isn't that much longer than a single typedef'd name.

Comment: With your typedef, a `llist` is the same as `struct node`...

Comment: Why past struct node, node is the type so why is struct needed?

Comment: @Celeritas In `C`, `struct node` is a type, but not `node`. In other languages like `C++`, `somename` is equivalent to `struct somename`.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

1. line 12: `void addToEnd(llist root, char entery[51])` shall be `void addToEnd(llist *root, char entery[51])`. Here root must be a pointer type or you actually can not modify its value inside the function and make it visible outside the function.
2. line 16: `node last = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` shall be `struct node *last = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`. Since in C you must reference a type name with the keyword `struct`, and also it shall be a pointer or it cannot be initialized with malloc.

As for your `typedef` question, I believe it is optional and people use it only for convenience. Personally I don't use `typedef` on a `struct` very often.

**EDITED:**

Also your code comes with bugs. Sorry I was only focusing on the syntax before.

Please notice that `malloc` in C don't assure you that the allocated memory is zeored, it's actually could be anything inside. So you need to fill it manually: to add a line `last->next = NULL;` at the end of `addToEnd`.

Comment: @Celeritas I've already edited it in the post, which is about the `last->next = NULL;` one. :)

Answer (score 1):

To refer to your `struct` of the linked list, use `struct node`, after the `typedef`, you can also use `llist`. You can also ues, as the linked question uses.

```
typedef struct node
{
  char entery[51];
  struct node* next;
} node;
```

In this style, you can use `node` the same as `struct node`.

The syntax error you are facing is, you misused the arrow operator `->`, it's used with **pointers** of `struct`. For `struct`, use the dot operator `.`

So for the function

```
void addToEnd(llist root, char entery[51])
{
    while(root->next != NULL)
        root = root->next;
```

You should pass in a pointer:

```
void addToEnd(llist* root, char entery[51])
```