# Inserting an element at 0th index of an array

Tags: arrays

How to insert an element at 0th index of an array except to shift all the elements one by one with increasing one size. Please suggest me another approach

Its an logic building problem and I am expecting a better code than mine

Comment: It depends on the type of programming language used. In general a linked list can be a solution

Comment: I am a beginner coder, so I want to do in C language

Comment: ` I want to do in C language` - It seems to me that you like it the hard way ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a linked list in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982388/how-to-implement-a-linked-list-in-c)