# Freeing a struct array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I looked for something like this before I posted this post and couldn't find..

I have:

```c
struct foo* fooArray= malloc(sizeof(*fooArray)*5);
struct foo* newFoo = malloc(sizeof(*newFoo));
fooArray[0]=*newFoo;
struct foo* newFoo2 = malloc(sizeof(*newFoo2));
fooArray[1]=*newFoo2;
```

How do I free each of the elements in fooArray?

```
free(&fooArray[0]); // Gives me error
free(fooArray[0]); // Doesn't compile
```

Comment: Why are you allocating a pointer in `newFoo`? I think you want to allocate a `foo` struct instead, as in `malloc(sizeof(foo))`.

Comment: Almost none of this code actually makes sense

Comment: Do: `free(fooArray);`. `free()` expects a pointer returned by malloc family functions. Am not sure what your intention is with all those assignments...If that's exactly what you code looks like then you have many more issues...

Comment: I am trying to save an array of foo struct and then I want to free each of its elements. The code does save an array of structs.

Comment: You can only free what you've allocated. If you allocated the whole array, you must free the whole array. You cannot choose to free things individually unless you allocated them individually. 1 malloc, 1 free, no exceptions.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker So how can I free newFoo, if I only have fooArray?

Comment: You did `newFoo = malloc()...`, so `free(newFoo)`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I don't have newFoo, I only have fooArray..Is fooArray[0]=NULL enough?

Comment: No! You allocated it with `fooArray = malloc()...`, so you have to free it with `free(fooArray)`. You CANNOT free less than you allocated. If you need to free the elements of fooArray idividually, then you must allocate them individually. 1 malloc, 1 free, no exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

First of all this code

```
struct foo* fooArray= malloc(sizeof(*fooArray)*5);
struct foo* newFoo = malloc(sizeof(*newFoo));
fooArray[0]=*newFoo;
struct foo* newFoo2 = malloc(sizeof(*newFoo2));
fooArray[1]=*newFoo2;
```

is invalid.

I think you mean the following

```
struct foo** fooArray= malloc(sizeof(*fooArray)*5);
struct foo* newFoo = malloc(sizeof(newFoo));
fooArray[0]=newFoo;
struct foo* newFoo2 = malloc(sizeof(newFoo2));
fooArray[1]=newFoo2;
```

To free only these two allocated elements newFoo and new Foo2 you can write for example

```
free( fooArray[0] );
free( fooArray[1] );

fooArray[0] = NULL;
fooArray[1] = NULL;
```

If you want also to free the entire array then you can write

```
free( fooArray[0] );
free( fooArray[1] );

free( fooArray );
```

Comment: Actually it does work for me as I wrote..it saves an array of foo's without **

Comment: @Lee  As I wrote your code is invalid. You should decide whether you want to create an array of 5 pointers to objects of the structure or an array of 5 objects of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct foo* fooArray= malloc(sizeof(*fooArray)*5);
```

when you allocate fooArray, you allocate ONE buffer of
size 5 times a struct foo. If you want to hold 5 struct foo's, you are good, but you don't have to malloc the array members:

```
struct foo* newFoo = fooArray
struct foo* newFoo2 = fooArray + 1;
struct foo* newFoo3 = &fooArray[2]; /* array notation */
```

..and you can only free them all at once

```
free(fooArray);
```

BUT...

If you want a set of 5 pointers The size is wrong,
and the data type on the left is wrong.

```
struct foo* fooArray= malloc(sizeof(*fooArray)*5);
```

should read:

```
struct foo** fooArray = malloc(sizeof(struct foo*) * 5);
```

It is a pointer to 5 pointers.
Then your array notation can work for allocation and freeing.

```
fooArray[0] = malloc(sizeof struct foo);
free(fooArray[0]);
```

BTW, if you want an "array" to grow and shrink dynamically, you don't wan't an array. you want a [Single linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973654/single-linked-list)

Just include a (struct foo*) pointer in struct foo and you can do away with fooArray.